# nvd3 charting, how to remove the time range slider (smaller chart below the chart)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nvd3.js, angularjs-nvd3-directives

Here is a Plunkr of what I want the chart in my app to look like: http://plnkr.co/edit/19D5cnrVYdUrMlblQARy?p=preview

There is no timespan range finder at all.

However in my app I'm seeing this:

[image]

My renderChart function:

```
function renderChart(ticker, limit) {
    TickerChartFactory.returnTickerChartData(ticker, limit).then(
        function(res) {
            console.log('res =',res);

            if (res.data.status === 'Success') {
                console.log('res.data.quotes =',res.data.quotes);

                var data_array = [];
                for (var i=0; i<res.data.quotes.length; i++) {
                    data_array.push([res.data.quotes[i].start_epoch, res.data.quotes[i].price]);
                }

                vm.tickerPrice.chartData = [
                    {
                        "area": true,
                        "key": "Price",
                        "color": '#BFBFBF',
                        "values": data_array
                    }
                ];

                console.log('vm.tickerPrice.chartData =',vm.tickerPrice.chartData);

                drawChart(vm.tickerPrice.chartData);
            }
            else {
                console.log('There was an error in retrieving quote data');
            }
        });
}
```

Then my drawChart function:

```
function drawChart(res) {
    console.log(' ');
    console.log('drawChart res = ',res);
    nv.addGraph(function() {
        var chart = nv.models.linePlusBarChart()
            .margin({top: 30, right: 40, bottom: 50, left: 40})
            .x(function(d,i) { return i })
            .y(function(d) { return d[1] })
            .color(d3.scale.category10().range());

        chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
            var dx = res[0].values[d] && res[0].values[d][0] || 0;
            return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(dx))
        });

        chart.y1Axis
            .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));

        chart.y2Axis
            .tickFormat(function(d) { return '$' + d3.format(',f')(d) });

        chart.bars.forceY([0]);

        d3.select('#chart svg')
            .datum(res)
            .transition().duration(500)
            .call(chart);

        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

        return chart;
    });
}
```

What the response looks like in the console

[image]

I haven't found anything in [their docs](http://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#line) that shows me how to remove it.

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the tool tip? As in you don't want the information box to pop up when the mouse is hovered over the graph? I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: Not not the tooltip, the timespan range finder below the normal chart.

Comment: Still no real solution, I'm currently using a hack on my `#chart` container to shorten the height of the svg so it hides the time range slider.

Answer (score 0):

The following line of code should remove the range slider:

```
chart.focusEnable(false)
```